# Need to restart App Engine Server when modifying a Servlet

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, servlets, jetty

Why do I need to restart `App Engine` Server (Jetty) inside of `Eclipse` when I modify a `Servlet` but not when I'm modifying a `Jsp` file? even if the `Jsp` file is converted to a `Servlet` by the Servlet container.

I'm having the same issue with `Tomcat`inside of `Eclipse`, for a normal Web application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the servlet container is the one that compiles the JSPs into servlets. It can thus easily detect when a `JSP` has been modified, `recompile it on the fly` and reload the new generated servlet class.

`Servlets`, on the other side, are `compiled before being deployed`, and they're not supposed to be modified without redeploying the application.

Comment: But the `jsp` is deployed to Tomcat as a `class` file. What makes it different from the same `servlet` `class` file?  When you say that it's the servlet container who compile the `jsp into servlet`, does it mean that the compilation of `servlet to class` is done by another component?

Comment: No, usually, the JSP file is deployed as is, and the container compiles it into a servlet .java, then .class file.